# Counter number of times a user triggers failed logon in powershell

Tags: powershell

My plan is to create a script that will gather each previous day's worth of failed logins from the security log. I want a way to count the number of times the same user triggers an alert since the end goal is to build a simple web site that displays the username, the number of failed logons they triggered and the name of the server where the alert was triggered. I have the start below:

```
#get a list of all disabled user email address and store it in 
disabledUsers variable
$disabledUsers = Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase 
"OU=Users,OU=Disabled,OU=COMPANY,DC=example,DC=local" -Properties mail | select -expandproperty mail

#empty array that will store all the usernames parsed below
$userArray = @()

#iterate through each user account in the disabledUsers variable
foreach ($user in $disabledUsers){

#for every email address, split the value based at the @ symbol and retrieve the first field/index and add that to the userArray array
$userArray += $user.Split("@")[0]}

#sets the previous day's time and date
$yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)

#get all failed login attempts since yesterday and extract the time of the error, server where error was logged, and user account that triggered the error
$failedLogins = get-eventlog -LogName Security -After $yesterday -EntryType FailureAudit -InstanceId 4625 | select timewritten,machinename,@{n='account';e={$_.replacementstrings[5]}}

#iterate through each entry in the failedLogins variable
foreach ($failedLogin in $failedLogins) {

<# define a counter variable to increment the check between the username in each failed event log against each 
   username defined in the userArray array. Loop keeps checking until $i is greater than or equal to the number of 
   entries in the userArray array
#>
for ($i=0; $i -lt $userArray.Length; $i++) {

    #everytime $i is not equal or greater than # of counts in userArray, check and see if the 
    #username in the event log matches the current username in the userArray index (represented by the $i)
    if ($failedLogins.account -match $userArray[$i]) {

        #if there is a match......

    } else {

    }
}
}
```

I'm not sure how best to build this counter. In case anyone is wondering, the use case for this is because we started noticing a bunch of failed login attempts from a disabled user account about once every 1-2mins. Trying to build a way to monitor this.

Comment: `$FailedLogins | Group-Object -Property Account`

Comment: cool, tested that on a different script i'm working on and looks like that does what i need. Thanks!